# asp.net web service login

Tags: asp.net

I have a login system using forms authentication, the problem is I want login and register links if the user is not logged in and if the user is logged in I want welcome username and a logout link. My website is using master page for a consistent layout so I am assuming all the code will go in there..

I am thinking on the page load I will have something like this:

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        label1.Text = User.Identity.Name;
    }
```

But I get user does not exist in the current context.

Thanks

Comment: Did you already consider using [asp:LoginName](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130045/143302) and [asp:LoginView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview) controls?

Comment: ahhh I hadn't and sorry I wasn't looking for code samples just a nudge in the right direction. But thanks, that's just what I needed.

Comment: Always glad to help ;-) Why not answer your own question and earn yourself the `Self Learner` badge?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to filbert. Here is the answer:

```
<asp:LoginView ID="RegisterLink" runat="server">
<AnonymousTemplate>
<div class="titleRegistration">
  <a href="Register.aspx">Register</a> or 
</div>
</AnonymousTemplate>
<LoggedInTemplate>
    <div class="titleRegistration">
        Hi <b><asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" />!</b>
    </div>
</LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
<asp:LoginStatus ID="lsGeneral" runat="server" LogoutPageUrl="/Users/Logout.aspx" />
```

Thanks Filbert.